# Convert size_t to vector<unsigned char>

Tags: c++, vector, byte, unsigned-char

I want to convert size_t to vector of unsigned chars. This vector is defined as 4 bytes.
Could anybody suggest a suitable way to do that?

Comment: This would be wrong thing to do - size_t in 2016 normally would not fit in the vector of 4 uchars.

Comment: If you want unsigned chars, create a `vector<unsigned char>`. `uint8_t` is not required to be a synonym for `unsigned char`; in fact there are architectures where 'uint8_t' does not exist, but `unsigned char` does.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Though to be fair, if you're on an architecture where `uint8_t` does not exist, there's a good chance that `unsigned char` does not represent an 8-bit byte.

Comment: @NicolBolas - not just a good chance, a certainty. But the question says it's about `unsigned char`, and, in fact, using `unsigned char` makes much better sense for this problem than restricting the code to only run on systems that have a native 8-bit unsigned type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've reconciled yourself to the fact that your `std::vector` is probably going to have to be bigger than that - it will need to have `sizeof(size_t)` elements - one well-defined way is to access the data buffer of such an appropriately sized vector and use `::memcpy`:

```
size_t bar = 0; /*initialise this else the copy code behaviour is undefined*/
std::vector<uint8_t> foo(sizeof(bar)); /*space must be allocated at this point*/
::memcpy(foo.data(), &bar, sizeof(bar));
```

There is an overload of `data()` that returns a non-`const` pointer to the data buffer. I'm exploiting this here. Accessing the data buffer in this way is unusual but other tricks (using unions etc.) often lead to code whose behaviour is, in general, undefined.

Comment: There is nothing unusual about it, in my view. Accessing allocated vector through data() is an honored thing.

Answer (score 1):

By "convert", I'll assume you mean "copy", since `vector` will allocate and own its memory. You can't just give it a pointer and expect to use your own memory.

An efficient way to do so which avoids two-stage construction (that causes initialization of the array with zero) is to do this:

```
auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&the_size);
vector<uint8_t> vec{ptr, ptr + sizeof(size_t)};
```

Note that `sizeof(size_t)` is not required to be 4. So you shouldn't write your code assuming that it is.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100406/discussion-on-answer-by-nicol-bolas-convert-size-t-to-vectorunsigned-char).

Answer (score 0):

You could write a generic converter using [std::bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<unsigned char> Type_To_Bit_Vector(T type, char true_char, char false_char){

    //convert type to bitset
    std::bitset<sizeof(type)*8> bset(type);

    //convert bitset to vector<unsigned char>
    std::vector<char> vec;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < bset.size() ; i++){
        if (bset[i]){
            vec.push_back(true_char);
        }else{
            vec.push_back(false_char);
        }
    }

    return vec;
}
```

---

You could then get a desired vector representation like so:

```
auto vec = Type_To_Bit_Vector(size_t(123),'1','0');
```

Comment: Thanx for bringing another option. Haven't tried yet. This sort of solution was actually on my mind at first place (sort of loop), but I was not aware of bitset in C++. Cool.